# Combining Two Near Identical MySQL Queries

Tags: mysql, union

New to this community... I have to say I love this resource though, it's fantastic. :)

(Before I go further, I want to point out that I have **already achieved** an undesirable yet functional solution to this problem using multiple queries and then combining what I get using a PHP array, but I'm weak with MySQL and what I've done simply isn't elegant or efficient, and I'd very much appreciate any assistance you can give me to actually help me improve it.  My project uses dozens and dozens of SQL queries and I'd like to learn to write them properly.)

I'm essentially trying to merge two near identical MySQL recordsets, using a UNION statement or something along those lines.  I've been looking around for ages trying to find a solution to this, and at this point it remains beyond me.  So, here's my first question:

My data structure is relatively simple, but I suspect the way in which I want to use it is perhaps a little less commonplace.  I have a series of users regularly transmitting data from their mobile devices to a PHP server which processes them and stores their contents in a MySQL database.  This is where it gets a little unorthodox, perhaps -- Users are effectively links in a closed chain.  At all times, every user has one other user serving as their link, or, I prefer, 'Target', while they themselves serve as the Target for someone else.  **This model can be thought of in a linear fashion: A targets B, B targets C, C targets D, D targets A.**

The data's stored in two tables:

1. *Users*: Contains data about users (e.g. UserID, Name, Age, etc etc... TargetID)
2. *Packages*: Contains data about all user updates (e.g. UserID, Timestamp, etc etc...)

Upon receiving a request from a user, I want to:

1. Firstly, pull the most recent update from the Packages table, along with biographical information from the Users table **pertaining to the Target of our User.**
2. Secondly, pull the most recent update from the Packages table, along with biographical information from the Users table **pertaining to whoever has our User as their Target.**

This might be a little confusing, so to clarify:
Using the aforementioned model, if I get a request from B, I want the most recent Package from A and the most recent Package from C returned in a single recordset, along with related biographical information.  **I'm not actually interested in B!**

The best I have managed to achieve at this point involves THREE queries:

1. Initially, checking the Users table for the correct TargetID for our User.

   ```
   SELECT TargetID FROM Users WHERE Users.UserID = [VALUE SUBMITTED IN USER REQUEST];
   ```
2. Querying both tables to produce Result 1.

   ```
   SELECT Users.UserID, Users.Name, Users.TargetID, Packages.Timestamp, Packages.Latitude, Packages.Longitude, Packages.Message FROM Users, Packages WHERE Packages.UserID = Users.UserID AND Users.UserID = [VALUE OBTAINED FROM QUERY 1] ORDER BY Packages.Timestamp DESC LIMIT 0,1;
   ```
3. Querying both tables to produce Result 2.

   ```
   SELECT Users.UserID, Users.Name, Users.TargetID, Packages.Timestamp, Packages.Latitude, Packages.Longitude, Packages.Message FROM Users, Packages WHERE Packages.UserID = Users.UserID AND Users.TargetID = [VALUE SUBMITTED IN USER REQUEST] ORDER BY Packages.Timestamp DESC LIMIT 0,1;
   ```

Then I've merged Results 1 & 2 in a PHP array, and fired the contents of this array back to the User submitting the request.  In any situation involving many many such requests, I have a hard time believing this approach is efficient, let alone ideal.  Despite the fact Queries 2 & 3 are virtually identical, and I'm sure a simple OR condition within a WHERE clause should be able to combine them, I cannot successfully do so without returning all Packages for both the users I'm interested in, or alternatively, returning exactly one record, discarding the second (I clearly apply the time constraint incorrectly).  For example, MySQL complains I incorrectly use UNION And ORDER BY statements together at times.  I'm just getting the syntax all wrong every time I try to modify it.

I am really unhappy with my current solution, because looking at my project at this point it is the single MySQL task my server must execute more often than all others.  I do realise this question is rather verbose, but I think it is always better to explain things thoroughly so it can be understood the first time.  Thanks in advance for any guidance or direction you can give me.  Cheers.

Comment: I'm a little confused.  You said that you're not actually interested in B, but in query 3, it looks like you're returning information on B when in fact (if I'm understanding correctly) you actually want the information on A?

Comment: Sorry if this is a bit ambiguous, but Query 3 is designed to return data relating to whoever has User as their Target.  To link the two tables of data, I used:  WHERE Packages.UserID = Users.UserID.  The data returned appears to indicate it does what I want, give me information about the targeting user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, something like:

```
select 
Users.UserID, 
TargetedPackages.UserID as TargetedID,
TargetedPackages.TimeStamp as TargetedTimestamp,
TargeterPackages.UserID as TargeterID,
TargeterPackages.Timestamp as TargetedTimestamp
from 
Users

INNER JOIN Users as Targeted
on Targeted.TargetId = Users.TargetID

INNER JOIN Users as Targeter
on Targeter.TargetId = Users.UserID

LEFT JOIN Packages as TargetedPackages
on Users.TargetID = TargetedPackages.UserID AND TargetedPackages.Timestamp = (SELECT Max(Timestamp) FROM Packages where Packages.UserID = Users.TargetID)

LEFT JOIN Packages as TargeterPackages
on Targeter.UserID = TargeterPackages.UserID AND TargeterPackages.Timestamp = (SELECT Max(Timestamp) FROM Packages where Packages.UserID = Targeter.UserID)

where Users.UserID = 2
```

Comment: With a little crashtesting, it would appear the above is pure wizardry.  Thanks for your time.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation. Welcome to StackOverflow!